# Create an array of external html pages and shuffle it into several divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, shuffle

I'm currently working on a site that consists in a grid of divs (4x4) into which a set of texts have to be shuffled at each reload. This basically looks [like this at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biEDj.png).

My index.htm reads :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="colonne">
<div class="case">
<span class="boxwatermark">1</span>
<span class="case1">
</span>
</div>
<div class="case">
<div class="boxwatermark">5</div>
<span class="case5">
</span>
</div>
<div class="case">
<div class="boxwatermark">9</div>
<span class="case9">
</span>
</div>
...
```

and so on up to 15 (16 remains empty).

The set of texts that I need to be distributed into the boxes (boxes = divs with classnames "case+number") are each in a separate html file (named "case1.html", "case2.html" etc.). I would like these html files to constitute the array, and this array to be shuffled "randomly" into each box.

I tried several things for the past two days, but the solution to this problem seems presently to exceed my (little) competences... I've been impressed by some of the attention given to such questions on this forum and decided to request your help. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Array.prototype.slice()`, `Array.prototype.splice()` , <strike>`.eq()`</strike> , `.each()` , `.load()`

```
$(function() {
  var c = "case";
  var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
  var copy = arr.slice(0);

  $("." + c).each(function() {
    var curr = copy.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length), 1)[0];
    $(this).load(c + curr + ".html")
  })

})
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/rAhq6fkbUqM3BfnahAVy?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

try this https://fiddle.jshell.net/

```
var shuffle = function (htmls) {
    for (var j, x, i = htmls.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = htmls[--i], htmls[i] = htmls[j], htmls[j] = x);
    return htmls;
};

var display = function (shuffledArray) {
    var index = 0;
    for (var spot in shuffledArray) {
        index++;
        var cssClass = '.case' + index;
        var div = document.querySelector(cssClass);
        div.innerHTML = shuffledArray[spot];
    }
}

if (!sessionStorage.getItem('htmlFiles')) {
    var htmls = [];
    htmls[0] = 'this a text for example';
    htmls[1] = 'Another text for example';
    htmls[2] = 'Yet anohter text for example';
    htmls[3] = 'The texts keep up comming';
    htmls[4] = 'More example texts here';
    htmls[5] = 'Even more texts';
    htmls[6] = 'The last example';
    sessionStorage.setItem('htmlFiles', htmls);
}
var htmls = sessionStorage.getItem('htmlFiles').split(',');

var shuffledArray = shuffle(htmls);
display(shuffledArray);
```